# Windows 8.1 App- Splash logo then a black screen?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, windows-store

[I submitted an app last night to the Windows Store](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-us/app/guitarcore/c904ea62-f596-47ff-ab28-c9bab29e6974). It ran, tested, and deployed just fine on the Surface Pro 3 I developed it on. I even trialed, purchased, and downloaded it to make sure the deployment was successful. All was good.

However, when I downloaded it to an old ASUS laptop running Windows 8.1 on my account, it opened to the splash and then the app screen went completely black. I do not have any other devices to test on other than my Surface and ASUS, and I'm concerned the issue might affect more devices. Is there any way to resolve this issue with the ASUS laptop? What would cause this behavior? I set up this Windows Store app to not be machine-specific.

You can also [download the trial here](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-us/app/guitarcore/c904ea62-f596-47ff-ab28-c9bab29e6974) to see this behavior (if it happens at all).

Comment: Hi there, is this a universal app or a non-mobile app only?  If it is non-mobile and you do not have a resolution I will download and check it out later.  I have an older Sony Vaio running 8.1 and a custom desktop running 8.1 that I can try it out on.

Comment: That'd be awesome thank you. It's a Windows Store app, so Windows 8.1 and Windows RT should run it.

Comment: Hi, I have had a similar experience in a `Windows Phone 8` project. The issue was that there was blocking code in the `Application_Startup` event handler. Now `Windows 8.1` does not have that, but has `ApplicationInitializationCallback` within the Application.Start(); maybe you check there if you can find anything there. Hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: My application is single-threaded, so I don' think there is any blocking. And it is very lightweight and quick to start. Good theory though, unless I'm missing something that is indeed causing blocking.

Comment: Ok, so I got home and installed the trial version.  I immediately ran into the same issue, splash screen and then just a black screen.  I opted to run it via a VS2013 debugger to see if some exception was occurring and then, after that, the app opened and ran no problem.  Now, when I run it standalone, just launching from start, it runs no problem...

Comment: Wow that is very bizarre... I hope Microsoft gets back to me today. I was worried Visual Studio created some resource it depends on that does not exist in deployment. I better take the app down until I get this resolved.

Comment: I'm resubmitting the app. I didn't do the certification test on the package before (I did it to the deployed test instance), so I did it this time according to the package deployment wizard. Let's hope for a different result...

Comment: I think it is fixed! Jason, if you have time would you mind updating and trying it on your computer again?